# Creating new styles with BasedOn in wpf

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to change a button I created so that it shows a grey color instead of a red one. However, I can change the foreground color, but not the one that is assigned to the elipse that is called 'buttonElipse'

```
<Style x:Key="RedRoundButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="SourceSansPro-Regular"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="36px"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource RedBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush  Color="White" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Stroke="{StaticResource RedBrush}" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="White" Name="buttonElipse"/>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="content"/>
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="buttonElipse" Property="Fill" Value="White" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="GreyRoundButton" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource RedRoundButton}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource GreyBrush}"/>
</Style>
```

I'm also wondering how i need to handle the same problem when I want to also override the colors in the triggers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a [TemplateBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742882.aspx). You want to modify the properties of items in the template based on the values of properties in the control that the template is applied to.

Given the template you have, I think all you need to do is modify what you are setting  the `Stroke` property to on the `Ellipse`:

```
<Ellipse Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" ... />
```

Then, anytime you change the `Foreground` property on the `Button`, you will also be changing the `Stroke` property on the `Ellipse`.

As far as changing the property in a template trigger, what you have should work fine. If you want to be able to externally configure what the mouse over color will be, then you may want to extend the `Button` class and add a new [DependencyProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx), named something like `MouseOverBrush`. Then you could use a template binding in the control template trigger to modify the `Ellipse` to use the value of that property when the mouse is over the `Button`.

For more information, read up on [Styling and Templating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx) and [Control Authoring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is use a resource dictionary for defining the colours

`{StaticResource xxx}`

e.g

```
<Setter TargetName="buttonElipse" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource ButtonEllipseOverBrush}" />
```

Then you can override the Buttons resources, providing different set of colours.